# Ubuntu 14.04 - Lightdm and Unity optimal configuration

Tags: unity, 14.04, graphics, lightdm, unity-dash

What I'm using:

- `SonyVaio Vpcef2e1e`

*(with 4GB RAM and `Ati mobility radeon™ hd 4250`)*

In the old days I never had issue with the graphics. I had to fight sometimes to add drivers to the graphic card but `Ubuntu`worked well, very well I had to say taking account of some older laptops I've used.

Since I began to see Unity, I began to have a lot of problems with my laptops, usually I follow some tutorials to deactivate Unity, or set Compiz to minimal configuration because the graphics were running badly.

I'm tired about following tutorials/guides about activate or deactivate this or that option... I would like to have some knowledge about what's going on with Unity, Compiz, Lightdm...

I've tried to found any information about those kind of things but I only find 2 kind of things:

- Easy tutorials to follow them as sheeps in a flock
- Very complex explanations about Ubuntu and it's graphical environment

**Questions**

- Can anybody tell me about any good book to teach myself in this kind of things ?
- Is there any kind of *bible tutorial* that I'm loosing ?
- Is there any kind of configuration that makes UnityDash don't crash ? *(I have drivers on my laptop, everything works well except this)*
- Also would like anybody to point me in a good direction to learn about the display manager `LightDM`

I know there is a lot of information, I've made a lot of research but although I've been using Linux for some years, I'm really noob about graphic issues, used to follow tutorials to fix concrete issues during this years, but I've never develop my understanding about it. I'm just looking for some good information to read about.

Comment: What are the exact spec of your GPU, I just read Ati mobility radeon™ hd 4250 is quite rubbish, Unity is a demanding GUI, simmeler to Windows AERO is requierments. The "bible" of tutorials as you call it is this https://help.ubuntu.com/

Comment: Thanks for the help, your comment is amazing and help me a lot. I supose I need a 600€ graphic card to run Ubuntu fine. Ah! And thanks for the link, I've never heard about https://help.ubuntu.com/

Comment: No you do not need a silly card for it, just try a desktop light version  http://lubuntu.net/ http://xubuntu.org/ They are fully featured 14.04 but have light desktops for lower gpu's, and you can still ask here for help. Find any pci-e GPU with 512mb of VRAM and it will work well, you will find them for like £50, im in UK so don't know exact price in doller but, try ebay